# Prove that if $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional subspaces of inner product spaces and $W\subset V$, then $W^{\bot}\supset V^{\bot}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

I want to prove the following:

> If $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional subspaces of inner product spaces and $W\subset V$, then $W^{\bot}\supset V^{\bot}$

I think I understand this in a qualitative way. If I have a basis for $W$, then this basis is entirely contained in $V$. The set of all vectors orthogonal to this basis $(W^{\bot})$ will contain the set of vectors orthogonal to $V$ since the basis of $W$ is in $V$ so $V^{\bot}$ is the same as $W^{\bot}$ when $W$ and $V$ have the **same** basis. If $V$ has more vectors in its basis than $W$'s basis, then $V^{\bot}$ is $W^{\bot}$ without whatever vectors that aren't orthogonal to all vectors in the basis of $V$.

**I have 2 questions**:

**1)** How do I quantify this proof? (**answered** by @*paul blart math cop*, my new favorite username)

**2)** What is the significance of inner-product space here?

Comment: Thinking of bases is unnecessary in my eyes. You can prove this directly. Take an element in $V^\perp$. Prove it's in $W^\perp$ by definition.

Comment: If $x \bot V$, then $x \bot W$ since $W \subset V$.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop first of all, I love your username. Second, if I'm understanding correctly, all I've gotta do is say "Choose some element of $V^{\bot}$. That is, some vecotor that is orthogonal to every vector in $V$. Since all vectors in $W$ are contained in $V$, then this chosen element is orthogonal to all vectors of $W$ and is therefore contained in $W^{\bot}$"? If so, that makes sense and is simpler

Comment: Yup that's exactly what I had in mind, nice work!